# What is the const-ness of dynamic cast of a pointer-type class member

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constants, dynamic-cast

The following simple programm fails to compile with MSVC but not with GCC and Clang? (i.e. MSVC triggers the `static_assert`).

```
#include <utility>

class Element {
    virtual ~Element() = default;
};


struct Proxy {

    Element* e{};
};

int main() {

    Proxy p;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(dynamic_cast<const Element*>(p.e)), const Element*>::value, "not const???" );

}
```

I think the [standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.dynamic.cast#1) is quite clear:

> The result of the expression dynamic_cast(v) is the result of
>   converting the expression v to type T. T shall be a pointer or
>   reference to a complete class type, or “pointer to cv void.” The
>   dynamic_cast operator shall not cast away constness
>   ([expr.const.cast]).

Is there some other part in the standard that supports MSVC here, or is it a compiler bug? Or even UB? But if so, why?

Live code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/cH2pfX).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a compiler bug. [[expr.dynamic.cast]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.dynamic.cast#3) implies the result should be a pointer to a const-qualified class type.

> If the type of v is the same as T, or it is the same as T except that
>   the class object type in T is more cv-qualified than the class object
>   type in v, the result is v (**converted if necessary**).

I emphasized "converted if necessary" because it applies to the const qualification of the class type, I believe.